# sed regex to clean input domain list of www. www1. ftp. etc

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I have tried so many combinations and suggestions now to get this to work but I am just not succeeding.

UPDATE: to Provide more info

I have an input list like this

```
0------------0-------------0.0n-line.info
0-0--0-000.com
0-3.us
aw.dermalmask.com
idolstudio.free.fr
idolstudio2.free.fr
something.blogspot.com
anything.blogspot.com
xxx.blogspot.ca
www.hola.org
www10.a8.net
www11.alsto.com
www148.myquicksearch.com
ftp.thaitattoo.nl
ftp01.pornocrawler.ws
ftp04.pornocrawler.ws
g.blogads.com
wvw.tielecreidito-pe.com
```

And I was given a sed by someone which almost get's this right but is missing escaping some characters and stripping off some periods.

I am using

```
sed -r 's:(^.?(aw|www|ftp|ww|wvw)[[:alnum:]]?.|^..?)::g' input.txt > output.txt
```

But it gives me this output

```
-----------0-------------0.0n-line.info
.a8.net
.alsto.com
.pornocrawler.ws
0--0-000.com
3.us
8.myquicksearch.com
blogads.com
dermalmask.com
hola.org
mething.blogspot.com
olstudio.free.fr
olstudio2.free.fr
thaitattoo.nl
tielecreidito-pe.com
x.blogspot.ca
ything.blogspot.com
```

Instead of this

```
0-----------0-------------0.0n-line.info
0-0--0-000.com
0-3.us
dermalmask.com
idolstudio.free.fr
idolstudio2.free.fr
something.blogspot.com
anything.blogspot.com
xxx.blogspot.ca
hola.org
a8.net
alsto.com
myquicksearch.com
thaitattoo.nl
pornocrawler.ws
pornocrawler.ws
blogads.com
tielecreidito-pe.com
```

And Ultimately I would actually like this kind of output.

```
0n-line.info
0-0--0-000.com
0-3.us
dermalmask.com
idolstudio.free.fr
idolstudio2.free.fr
something.blogspot.com
anything.blogspot.com
xxx.blogspot.ca
hola.org
a8.net
alsto.com
myquicksearch.com
thaitattoo.nl
pornocrawler.ws
pornocrawler.ws
blogads.com
tielecreidito-pe.com
```

Comment: Are you able to use more than one regex?

Comment: Yes indeed, I could do this in multiple stages if necessary. ie. `run regex1 input > tmp` .... `run regex2 tmp > tmp2` .... `run regex3 tmp2 > tmp3 && mv tmp3 finaloutput` or something like that and cleanup tmp files or do something like `run regex1 input > tmp` ... `run regex2 tmp > input` ... `run regex3 input > tmp` etc

Answer (score 0):

I think your last line is www.tielecreidito-pe.com and not wvw...

So you can try this one

```
sed '1s/[^.]*.//;s/^[w\|a]w[^\.]*.\|^[f\|g][^\.]*.//' infile
```

Comment: Thanks @ctac_ I will try this tomorrow afternoon, been out of the office all day and will be out most of tomorrow too. But I will get back to you, thanks so much for your help.